# Use MVVM for WPF dialog box

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I want to use MVVM in my WPF application.  I currently have a Model and a view which has DataGrid and some other controls.  I created a ViewModel based on my model and don't know if I did it correctly.  The view is just a simple dialog box.  I want to fill the DataGrid view.

How can I tell the DataGrid to bind with the ViewModel?

**I would like to bind properties(inside viewmodel like ID and Date) to the datagrid**.

**SO like if there is two objects inside the list I would like to see two rows in datagrid with the specific ID's and Date's.**

Im setting the datacontext inside the class instead xaml.

Here is the code so far:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private DateTime _date;
    private ObservableCollection<Object> _list;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            PropertChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            PropertChanged("Date");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Object> list
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            PropertChanged("list");
        }
    }

    public LicenseViewModel()
    {
        list = GetList();
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void PropertChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Import"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
      x:Name="ImportLicense"
      d:DesignHeight="493" d:DesignWidth="559"
      Title="Import Licenses" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid Width="538">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Imported" VerticalAlignment="Top"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Entitlement ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Sold" Binding="{Binding Path=Date}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I got it resolved by using itemsources on back side with the viewModel instead inside xaml.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the data context for the `DataGrid` to the instance of your view model.  You can do this by simply setting the `DataContext` of your View or the DataGrid to your instance of your view model in the constructor of the view class.  This is a quick and dirty way of doing this.

If you want to be more sophisticated you can create a `DepenencyProperty` on your view class like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel",
        typeof(ItemViewModel),
        typeof(ViewClassHere));

public ItemViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (ItemViewModel)base.GetValue(ItemViewModel); }
    set { base.SetValue(ItemViewModel, value); }
}
```

Then you'd bind to that property in any one of many ways but one way would be like:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=windowName, Path=viewName.list}">
```

There are a bunch of ways to do this, these are just two possible ways to do this.

Comment: One thing I couldn't understand is how come the viewModel can associate with datagrid.And how the each property inside the viewmodel could automatically bind to the datagrid's columns. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Let explain in detail what im askin: after the datacontext will call the constructor of viewMOdel which will internally will populate the list.BUt what about the other two properties ID and Date. How can they bind with the datagrid.

Comment: @alice7 I'm sorry I was not thinking correctly when you bind to the data grid you want to not bind the DataContext to your view but to bind the ItemsSource so that ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=windowName, Path=viewName.list}"

Comment: I got that resolved. Instead of doing in xaml, I have done the binding behind in .cs file using itemsources to the viewModel and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the common way to display data with a datagrid is to set the itemssource

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
```

your viewmodel defines 2properties and one collection, but in your xaml you bind your properties to the datagrid columns and don't set any itemssource.

its not clear to me what you would like to see in your datagrid, but your 2 properties ID and DateTime are not part of any collection, so why you want this to display in your datagrid?

please edit your question and give some information of what you wanna see in your datagrid.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for not being clear what i want. I would like to see those properties inside viewmodel to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<window.Resources>             
<ViewModel  x:Key="ViewModel"></ViewModel >
</window.Resources>
<Grid  x:Name="ValueDetail"  DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/> 
</Grid>
```